# using where clause in haskell causing error?

Tags: haskell

I am new in haskell trying to do a small task

```
get1th ( a , _, _ , _) = a
foo input = 
    where input = (a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_)
    if ( length (get1th input) == 2 ) 
        then permutations[2]
        else permutations[3]
```

I am getting error saying

```
 parse error on input `where'
```

please give me a hint

Comment: This is not how `where` is used. Take a look here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where

Answer (score 3):

`where` clause must be written at the end:

```
foo input = 
    if ( length (get1th input) == 2 ) 
        then permutations[2]
        else permutations[3]
    where (a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) = input
```

UPDATED

It is also require to swap to `(a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) = input`, reason - we want to extract values, but not to redefine `input`

Comment: ...but this is still really broken.

Comment: @user2277918 : correct last line to `where (a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) = input`

Comment: The `where` clause seems totally unnecessary since none of the extracted values are used, and the failure to pattern match will result in an exception.  At best, it restricts the inferred type of input to a 4-tuple of lists of something...  Also, the `permutations[2]` looks like array indexing, but it is actually applying the `permutations` function to the list containing a single `2`, which does not have a very interesting result.

Answer (score 1):

As @wit has pointed out, `where` should be used in the end of expression. Why? Because:

1. it is not a `let`;
2. because it is related with all the previous context (block) of the function.

If you want to define an *alias* fronthand, you should use the `let` expression.

For more information about the differences and advantages of them, see the [Let vs. Where](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where).